# RabbitMQ Clustering

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-cluster

In my case:

- I have 3 nodes in cluster.
- RabbitMQ_node1 is leader of queue A and have no mirror.
- When I pub messages with persistence mode with connection to RabbitMQ_node2 I see message will
  store in RabbitMQ_node1.

I read it in document of RabbitMQ:

- Assuming all cluster members are available, a client can connect to any node and perform any operation. Nodes will route operations to the quorum queue leader or queue leader replica transparently to clients.

I try to log about this event, I want to see how RabbitMQ_node2 can route operations to RabbitMQ_node1(Queue Leader): Log, send event or anything else. Thank for your help.

Comment: your question isn't very clear. are you trying to understand how to capture logs within a container orchestration system? what methods have you tried?

Comment: I using Docker to create cluster. I pub message with connection to rabbitmq_node2 and i don't see any log in rabbitmq log file about rabbitmq_node2 route operations to rabbitmq_node1. in my view, i want to see this event.
Ex: Connect to rabbitmq_node2 => pub message to queue(node1 is a leader) => see event how rabbitmq_node2 route operation to rabbitmq_node1. Thank for your advice.

Comment: I try to config logging options, tracing plugin and it do not solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

> I try to log about this event, I want to see how RabbitMQ_node2 can route operations to RabbitMQ_node1(Queue Leader): Log, send event or anything else

RabbitMQ does not log inter-node communication. The closest you'll get is to take a packet capture from the distributed Erlang TCP connections. By default RabbitMQ configures Erlang to listen on port `25672` for distributed Erlang.